# variable declared in jsp gives previous values on click in a different jsp, where as the java value is correct

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp

```
<s:set name="deletedProductId" value="%{serviceOrder.serviceOrderProducts[#attr.varStatus.index].productLineNumber}"/>
<s:set name="deletedProductId" value='%{serviceOrder.id + ":" + #attr.deletedProductId}'/>
```

the above line of code is the way the deleted productId is declared in jsp

```
<a href="serviceOrder!deleteServiceOrderProduct.action?id=<s:property value='%{entity.id}'/>&&deletedProductId=<s:property value='%{#attr.deletedProductId}'/>" onClick="return confirmDeleteProduct()">
    <img src="${imageUrlBuilder.getImageUrl('icon_record-delete.gif')}" alt="<s:text name="serviceOrder.serviceOrderProducts.delete.info"/>" title="<s:text name="serviceOrder.serviceOrderProducts.delete.info"/>"/>
</a>
```

This is the way in which the confirm deleteproduct is called.

```
function confirmDeleteProduct() {
    alert('${deletedProductId}');
    alert('${productDeletableOnServiceOrder}');
    <s:if test="%{!productDeletableOnServiceOrder}">
        alert('${serviceOrderHasJob}');
        return false;
    </s:if>
    return confirm('${confirmDeleteProduct}');
}
```

once the page loads and we are clicking on the delete icon. the alert popup gives null value for deletedProductId().  Is there a way I cannot get the null value and get the current value that I am clicking on?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: I can't make heads or tails of what your code is doing, but it seems like you might be confusing code that executes on the server (JSP, tags, etc) vs. code that executes on the client (JS). Are you certain you're clear on the difference?

Comment: we set the deletedproduct id in one jsp, and we are using its value in the other jsp, despite of clicking on the delete button on first jsp the actual id is not generated but in java when we do getDeletedId we get the actual id. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thank you jean for editing http://stackoverflow.com/users/5846066/jean-maxime-bouloc